# JAX RS : Cannot cast JSON to Object with Websphere liberty core

Tags: java, spring-boot, jax-rs, websphere-liberty

Using a spring boot application and trying to call a WS from an API,

It works correctly on my local machine but when executing in WAS, it throws errors :

```
A a = apiC.target("https://website/ddd")
            .request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).get(A.class);
```

Spring boot => return Object A

Spring boot servlet with WebSphere WAS => exception :

```
ERROR org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils - Problem with reading the data, class java.lang.A, ContentType: text/plain;charset="UTF-8".
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: Problem with reading the data, class java.lang.A, ContentType: text/plain;charset="UTF-8"
```

.

EDIT :

If i run this code to retrieve json as String Object => it works correctly !

```
Client apiClient = ClientBuilder.newClient();
            WebTarget resource = apiClient.target("https://cview");
            Builder request = resource.request();
            request.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
            Response response =  request.get();
logger.info( response.readEntity(A.class).toString());
```

So that means that the API works correctly and accept application-json  **BUT** when i try to cast it with an Object (A)
it shows me that error.

Comment: Bad content type? (text)

Comment: can you provide more detail on the code that is being run inside Liberty? such as what API `.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)` is coming from? Based on the error message it looks like the API call is not configured to accept JSON content

Comment: error occured when i try to cast it in WebSphere

Comment: The response content-type is 'text/plain'. There is no such provider that converts text/plain to Pojo. You need to either figure out why server is returning content-type text/plain and fix it, or [set the content-type manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51249404/2587435) to application/json on the response before deserialization